# How we can use swiper slider with data attributes to access it's functionalities from attributes value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, custom-data-attribute, swiper.js

I am trying to create a responsive swiper slider with the help of data attributes to access swiper slider functionalities.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="swiper-container " data-slidespace="30" data-smView="1" data-mdView="2"
data-lgView="3" data-xlView="4">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="swiper-container " data-slidespace="15" data-smView="1" data-mdView="2"
data-lgView="2" data-xlView="3">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Below IS my JS code:

```
$(".swiper-container").each(function() {
        var web_slider = $(this);
        web_slider.Swiper({
            spaceBetween: web_slider.data("slidespace"),
            breakpoints: {
                320: {
                    slidesPerView: web_slider.data("smView"),
                },
                768: {
                    slidesPerView: web_slider.data("mdView"),
                },
                1024: {
                    slidesPerView: web_slider.data("lgView"),
                },
                1190: {
                    slidesPerView: web_slider.data("xlView"),
                }
            },
        });
    });
```

ERROR THAT I AM GETTING ::  **web_slider.Swiper is not a function
at HTMLDivElement..**
I am new to javascript and Jquery.
It would be great for me to correct my code or guide me with the correct solution.
Thank You

Comment: The issue is because `Swiper()` is not a method of a jQuery object, nor does the library attach to jQuery. Read the docs for examples of the correct way to access the Swiper instance: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api

Answer (score 0):

### Jquery approach

As commented by **Rory McCrossan** you can't mix jquery and native JS objects/nodes when initializing swiper.

Here's a modified version of your jquery script:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".swiper-container").each(function () {
    // convert jquery object to native node
    let web_slider = $(this)[0];
    let optionsData = web_slider.dataset;
    // set options for swiper
    let options = {
      spaceBetween: optionsData.slidespace,
      breakpoints: {
        320: {
          slidesPerView: optionsData.smview
        },
        768: {
          slidesPerView: optionsData.mdview
        }
      }
    };

    // init
    new Swiper(web_slider, options);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper swiper-container " data-slidespace="30" data-smView="2" data-mdView="3" data-lgView="4" data-xlView="4">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="swiper swiper-container " data-slidespace="15" data-smView="1" data-mdView="2" data-lgView="2" data-xlView="3">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, we're just converting the Jquery object to a native JS equivalent like so:

```
let web_slider = $(this)[0];
```

and then populate the swiper.js options object by retrieving the data attributes

```
// set options for swiper
let options = {
  spaceBetween: optionsData.slidespace,
  breakpoints: {
    320: {
      slidesPerView: optionsData.smview
    },
    768: {
      slidesPerView: optionsData.mdview
    }
  }
};

// init
new Swiper(web_slider, options);
```

#### This approach has some drawbacks:

1. You need an **additional abstraction** to assemble multiple data attributes to the final swiper.js compliant options object.
2. there's no real benefit parsing the data attributes via Jquery when the used library is based on **native java script objects**.

### Native Js approach

Since swiper.js isn't based/dependant on Jquery you should consider a "vanilla JS" approach.

As suggested by Roman Koff – have a look at
[pavelblednov's github gist](https://gist.github.com/pavelblednov/1ab7debae9fa9ee275d914ba04ffe7d4).

However, we can simplify/refine this approach even further by creating a more generic and versatile initialization helper function.

#### Define all options as a JSON string

Instead of adding multiple data-attributes, you can convert the options object as a JSOn string:

```
let options = {
  spaceBetween: 5,
  slidesPerView: 2
}
```

becomes

```
{"spaceBetween":5, "slidesPerView":2}
```

Obviously this object or JSON string must respect the current API [options/parameters](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters).

We need to be careful about the **enclosing quotes**. You can enclose the data attribute value in **single quotes** and object keys in double quotes like so:

```
<div class="swiper" data-swiper='{"spaceBetween":5, "slidesPerView":2}'>
```

This is a common practice used by many other sliders e.g [splide.js](https://splidejs.com/guides/options/#by-data-attribute) (vanilla js) [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) (jquery) supporting data-attribute settings out-of-the box.

### Options object to data attribute JSON string

More complex options can be slightly error-prone (e.g. missing quotes or curly brackets).
`JSON.stringify()` can help to get the correct JSON string:

```js
let options = {
  spaceBetween: 12,
  slidesPerView: 3,
  pagination: { el: ".swiper-pagination" },
  autoplay: { delay: "1000" },
  breakpoints: {
    // when window width is >= 320px
    320: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    // when window width is >= 480px
    480: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    // when window width is >= 640px
    640: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 40
    }
  }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(options));
```

#### JS example: use generic initializing function

```js
// basic options for all sliders
let defaults = {
  spaceBetween: 5,
  slidesPerView: 2
}
// call init function
initSwipers(defaults);

function initSwipers(defaults={}, selector='.swiper'){
  let swipers = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
  swipers.forEach(swiper=>{
    // get options
    let optionsData = swiper.dataset.swiper ? JSON.parse(swiper.dataset.swiper) : {};
    // combine defaults and custom options
    let options = {
      ...defaults,
      ...optionsData
    };
    // init
    new Swiper(swiper, options);
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper" data-swiper='{"spaceBetween":12,"slidesPerView":3,"pagination":{"el":".swiper-pagination"},"autoplay":{"delay":"1000"},"breakpoints":{"320":{"slidesPerView":2,"spaceBetween":20},"480":{"slidesPerView":3,"spaceBetween":30},"640":{"slidesPerView":4,"spaceBetween":40}}}'>
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
<div class="swiper" data-swiper='{"slidesPerView":4}'>
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

<h3>No data attribute - use defaults</h3>
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

### How it works

1. loop through all elements with a specified selector - default '.swiper'
2. retrieve data attribute and parse it `JSON.parse(swiper.dataset.swiper)`
3. We might want to specify **default options** applied to all instances and merge them with the individual data options. We can merge both objects via spread operator

   let options = {
   ...defaults,
   ...optionsData
   };

Parameters specified in the **data attribute will override defaults**.

For testing: See [codepen example.](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/RwqpjoW?editors=1000)